# Select query with logical operators as sub query

Tags: sqlite

I would like to run a conditional select query on a table of sewer structures (S_Structures) in SQLite. The table contains the following columns: `struct_type` (structure type) and `Year` (construction year).

The selection will be based on the structure type as well as structure age, I think I've sorted out the type selection bit and with regards to the age, I intend to deduct the year from the local time. This is all fine and well, but how do I go about defining a logical operator as sub query for the specified age range of: 2 < age <= 5.

```
 Select [Year],[Struc_Type]
 FROM [S_Structures]
 WHERE [Struc_Type] NOT IN 
 ("Manhole", "Rodding Eye", "Dummy",
   "End Manhole", "T-Piece", "Sub-  Catchment", "Top End");
 AND WHERE (strftime('%Y','now') - Year) > '2' 
 AND (strftime('%Y','now') - Year); <= '5';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery would involve an additional SELECT in parentheses.

Only a single WHERE clause is allowed.

Just use the [BETWEEN operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#between):

```
SELECT [Year], [Struc_Type]
FROM [S_Structures]
WHERE [Struc_Type] NOT IN ('Manhole', 'Rodding Eye', 'Dummy', 'End Manhole',
                           'T-Piece', 'Sub-Catchment', 'Top End')
  AND (strftime('%Y','now') - Year) BETWEEN 3 AND 5;
```